# What is the most efficient way to interchange the values of two variables in a Tensorflow graph?

Tags: tensorflow

Given a Tensorflow graph with two variables, var1 and var2, I want to assign the value of var1 to var2 and vice versa. One simple way of doing this is (MWE at end of post)

```
var_tmp = var1.eval(session=sess)
sess.run([tf.assign(var1, var2])
sess.run([tf.assign(var2, var_tmp)])
```

However, if there are several pairs of such variables (e.g. model parameters and associated exponentially weighted moving averages), this method quickly becomes rather slow since `run` is called three times for each and it actually creates a memory leak (https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/4151#issuecomment-244089247). Additionally, since var_tmp is placed on the CPU, if var1 and var2 are on a GPU, the execution is even slower due to data transfer.

For the case of several pairs of variables, I want to avoid creating an entire copy of the graph to hold the temporary variables.

Is it possible to define a single operation to do this for a pair of variables? Or even better, for several pairs?

MWE:

```
import tensorflow as tf

var1 = tf.Variable(1)  # 'Variable:0' 
var2 = tf.Variable(2)  # 'Variable_1:0'
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

var_tmp = var1.eval(session=sess)
sess.run([tf.assign(var1, var2)])
sess.run([tf.assign(var2, var_tmp)])

print(var1.eval(session=sess))
print(var2.eval(session=sess))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to use resource variables (with `tf.enable_resource_variables()` after 1.11, `tf.get_variable_scope().set_use_resource(True)` before then) and a graph like

```
 a_value = a.read_value()
 b_value = b.read_value()
 with tf.control_dependencies([a_value, b_value]):
   ops = a.assign(b_value), b.assign(a_value)

 sess.run(ops)
```

Comment: Nice solution, thanks a lot. Given a model and training pipeline, this changes all variables to resource variables as far as I can see. Are you aware of any "breaking" changes that this might bring with it?

Comment: There shouldn't be any regressions.

Comment: It appears that it influences Keras layers in some way. Batch normalisation layers following 2D convolutions return `None` gradients when computed by `optimizer.compute_gradients` but I haven't been able to pinpoint the reason. I'm leaving this comment here if anyone else encounters similar issues.

Comment: Is the issue that you're trying to backprop through assignments? That's not a thing tf lets you do.

Comment: That should not be the reason since I'm not trying to do that. But I guess it could be the reason for the error by accident. My `a` and `b` variables are respectively a trainable variable in a network and an (untrainable) exponential moving average of that variable. I'm toggling these at validation and training time, but the assignment operations should not be part of the training graph.

Answer (score 0):

Without going into the details of TensorFlow, I'll suggest you use this -

`var1, var2 = var2, var1`

If you'd like to swap multiple pairs, try -

```
for var1, var2 in pairs:
    var1, var2 = var2, var1
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes this changes the references of the python variables var1 and var2 but it does not change the value of the Tensorflow variable 'Variable:0" to that of "Variable_1:0" which is what I'm seeking

Comment: OK, my bad. I'll be looking for the answer.